# TaskBar ProjectName WIN10

Tags: wpf

[image]

Does anybody know why I don't have my projectname on the taskbar.
And does anybody know how to change the projectname on the taskbar?

Comment: *"Projectname"* is a bit misleading here - I guess you are asking how to change the Application title, right?

Comment: just have the solution from the 1st post.  yea i mean the Title

Answer (score 0):

In TaskBar should be displayed window.Icon & window.Title. Just change Title property for you MainWindow (Current Window):

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="My App Name"></Window>
```